# Error 500 while trying to set a variable in Jmeter

Tags: variables, groovy, jmeter

I tried to create a variable in groovy and Jmeter.
I want it to be the counter of a while loop that I am planning to run.
I want in each iteration to add 1 to this counter.
the problem is that I can not set it to be variable, that I could use later in the program in another sampler.

```
int while_counter = 0;
vars.put("while_counter",0);
System.out.println("Loop Counter");
```

I just want to create an integer that will be a counter and all the sampler will know, and can address him ${while_counter}.

and to perform while_counter = while_counter++
what I am missing

```
Response code: 500
Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables.put() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer) values: [while_counter, 0]
Possible solutions: put(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), get(java.lang.String), putAt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), wait(), any(), dump()
```

Can someone please advise how to create a simple while loop in Jmeter
and to add 1 to counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define variable "**i**" as 0/1 at start of Test Plan in [User Defined Variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables)/[User Parameters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters)

While loop condition:

```
${__groovy(vars["i"].toInteger() < 5)}
```

Inside loop add your [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)/[Preprocessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) with increment it:

```
  String i = vars.get("i"); 
  int counter = Integer.parseInt(i); 
  counter++; 
  vars.put("i", "" + counter);
```

**Don't use Javascript function as it doesn't scale as well as Groovy**

Comment: Thanks a lot man,   But if I have user defined variable that knows the loop iteration, and I want to create a variable using groovy to take its value, and to compare them can it be done?   now I have two user defined variables I for counting from 0, and array size that is 3. can I create a variable that include 3 and remove one user defined variable?

Comment: you can get the variable and save in another variable, for example if user defined is `counterI`, just change first line to get it  String i = `vars.get("counterI")`;

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to avoid scripting where possible so:

1. If you are running an "internal" loop driven by [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) or [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) it makes sense to add a [Counter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) test element which will generate an incrementing number each time it will be called. You will be able to refer counter's current value using "normal" JMeter variable defined in the counter's "Reference Name" section
2. For [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level iterations you can use [__iterationNum()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#iterationNumsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-1-font-sup) function

---

With regards to your question itself, you cannot pass an integer to `vars.put()` method if you need to store an integer in JMeter Variables you should go for [`vars.putObject()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) method instead.